# move row from UITableView to second UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 2 `UITableView`, my scenario is that I want to move row from first `UITableView` to second `UITableView`. I need help.

Comment: nice scenario, record the movie now. Did you try something ? or do you have something to show us ?

Comment: i have tried but no result. u have any idea.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/screenshot20110721at332.png see screenshot

Comment: do you need drag/drop functionality?

Comment: yes i need drag/drop funtionality from table to table ok...

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need drag/drop functionality(animations) then all you need to do is change the data in the individual data-sources for the two table-views and reload them both! This can be triggered , for eg, by a button. The data for a cell would be deleted from one table-view data-source and added to the other. The animations would be tricky! I'll start working on that right away and post here if something nice happens.
Hey... I've uploaded a (partially) working solution at [github](https://github.com/aakash272/dragDrop)

PS: It needs a lot of improvement. For now, you'll have to tap the cell to be dragged once, and then, hold and drag it to the required area.

Comment: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/577/screenshot20110721at332.png

Comment: I've uploaded a sample project at [github](https://github.com/aakash272/dragDrop)

Answer (score 0):

I have a basic implementation (with crap animations) here:
https://bitbucket.org/elmalabarista/dragdroptableviews